# How to prevent Shift+arrows to select text in Windows using autohotkey

Tags: windows, autohotkey

When we are in many windows programs (for example Notepad) keeping Shift down and then pressing arrows (left, right, up, down) results in selecting text.

Is there a way to prevent this behavior using autohotkey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want, you can use AutoHotkey to intercept the <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Left</kbd> and just send out a <kbd>Left</kbd>.

```
+Left::Send {Left}
```

Be aware that this will override ALL uses of <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Left</kbd>, so you may find unexpected behavior in other applications.